# How to inject spring beans into the hibernate envers RevisionListener

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-envers

I am using Spring 5.1 and Hibernate 5.3.9 including hibernate-envers.
I don't know how to inject spring beans into the hibernate envers custom RevisionListener.

I have tried

```
  (@Service or @Component)
  public class ExtendedRevisionListener implements RevisionListener {

  @Autowired
  private MyService myService;

  void newRevision(Object revisionEntity){
    myService.doSomething(...)
  }
}
```

Of course the class is included in the @ComponentScan packages resolution.
A problem is that  myService is not injected into the listener.

In the hibernate-envers documentation:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#envers-basics

*As of Hibernate Envers 5.3, dependency injection is now supported for a RevisionListener.
This feature is up to the various dependency frameworks, such as CDI and Spring, to supply the necessary implementation during Hibernate ORM bootstrap to support injection. If no qualifying implementation is supplied, the RevisionListener will be constructed without injection.*

Unfortunatelly i haven't found any  working example.

@Naros
I do a setup of the EntityMaganerFactoryBean in my spring persistence JPA 
configuration ->  entityManager = 
new org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean()

```
10:49| DEBUG | SessionFactoryImpl.java 252 | Session factory constructed with filter configurations : {}
10:49| DEBUG | SessionFactoryImpl.java 253 | Instantiating session factory with properties: {hibernate.format_sql=true, awt.toolkit=sun.awt.windows.WToolkit, hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=false, java.specification.version=1.8, logging.configuration=file:C:\wildfly16\standalone\configuration\logging.properties, sun.cpu.isalist=amd64, sun.jnu.encoding=Cp1250, sun.arch.data.model=64, org.jboss.resolver.warning=true, java.vendor.url=http://java.oracle.com/, javax.persistence.validation.mode=AUTO, sun.boot.library.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\bin, org.jboss.logmanager.nocolor=true, sun.java.command=org.jboss.modules.Main -mp C:\wildfly16\modules org.jboss.as.standalone -b localhost --server-config=standalone.xml -Djboss.server.base.dir=C:\wildfly16\standalone, java.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.as.naming.interfaces, java.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre, jboss.server.persist.config=true, file.separator=\, jboss.server.data.dir=C:\wildfly16\standalone\data, line.separator=
, java.vm.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation, java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification, jboss.server.base.dir=C:\wildfly16\standalone, hibernate.transaction.coordinator_class=class org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorBuilderImpl, wicket.configuration=development, jboss.bind.address.management=localhost, sun.boot.class.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\classes, hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update, user.script=, java.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.jboss.net.protocol|org.jboss.vfs.protocol, sun.management.compiler=HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers, java.runtime.version=1.8.0_201-b09, user.name=ptaszek, hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true, file.encoding=Cp1250, sun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000, java.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\ptaszek\AppData\Local\Temp\, org.jboss.boot.log.file=C:\wildfly16\standalone\log\boot.log, jboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman, java.version=1.8.0_201, java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification, jboss.bind.address=localhost, java.awt.printerjob=sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob, jboss.host.name=1501-10, org.jboss.security.context.ThreadLocal=true, sun.os.patch.level=, module.path=C:\wildfly16\modules, java.library.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;native;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_211/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_211/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_211/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AOMEI Backupper;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin\;C:\eclipse;;., jboss.server.name=1501-10, java.vendor=Oracle Corporation, jboss.modules.dir=C:\wildfly16\modules, sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle, jboss.server.temp.dir=C:\wildfly16\standalone\tmp, sun.desktop=windows, file.encoding.pkg=sun.io, hibernate.connection.handling_mode=DELAYED_ACQUISITION_AND_HOLD, hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect, java.class.path=C:\wildfly16\jboss-modules.jar, jboss.server.deploy.dir=C:\wildfly16\standalone\data\content, java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation, user.variant=, user.timezone=Europe/Belgrade, os.name=Windows 10, java.vm.specification.version=1.8, program.name=JBossTools: WildFly 16 at localhost, hibernate.generate_statistics=false, sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD, user.country=PL, hibernate.use_sql_comments=false, javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode=UNSPECIFIED, jboss.server.config.dir=C:\wildfly16\standalone\configuration, sun.cpu.endian=little, user.home=C:\Users\ptaszek, user.language=pl, jboss.qualified.host.name=1501-10, java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment, java.awt.headless=true, org.apache.xml.security.ignoreLineBreaks=true, sun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000, java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true, jboss.home.dir=C:\wildfly16, path.separator=;, os.version=10.0, java.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\endorsed, java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment, hibernate.ejb.persistenceUnitName=default, sun.nio.ch.bugLevel=, java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, hibernate.show_sql=false, java.security.auth.login.config=jar:file:/C:/wildfly16/modules/system/layers/base/org/picketbox/main/picketbox-5.0.3.Final.jar!/auth.conf, jboss.server.log.dir=C:\wildfly16\standalone\log, java.vendor.url.bug=http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/, user.dir=C:\wildfly16\bin, os.arch=amd64, org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy=org.hibernate.envers.strategy.ValidityAuditStrategy, javax.management.builder.initial=org.jboss.as.jmx.PluggableMBeanServerBuilder, hibernate.boot.CfgXmlAccessService.key=org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.spi.LoadedConfig@35a3f1ae, java.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager, java.vm.info=mixed mode, java.vm.version=25.201-b09, hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false, hibernate.connection.datasource=HikariDataSource (HikariCpConnectionPool), java.ext.dirs=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\lib\ext, jboss.node.name=1501-10, java.class.version=52.0}
```

In my PersistenceJPAConfig:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "pl.atmoterm", entityManagerFactoryRef = "localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean")

  @Bean
  @DependsOn({"dataSource"})
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean() {
     LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
     em.setDataSource(dataSource());
     em.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{
        "pl.atmoterm.**.*"
     });

     em.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
     em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
     return em;
  }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There really is not much involved in setting up bean injection with Spring Framework 5.1 and Envers.  The listener implementation does not require being annotated by `@Service` nor `@Component` because these classes are actually constructed by Hibernate and then the `ManagedBeanRegistry` is responsible for coordinating with whatever DI framework is being used to inject/wire dependencies.

If your `MyService` is not being injected into the revision listener then there are few things to check:

1. Verify that you're using *Spring Framework 5.1* or later.
   While other spring components may use differing version schemes, its important to make sure that the underlying Spring Framework version is indeed 5.1+.
2. Is the `RevisionListener` configured correctly?
   I typically configure this by adding a `@RevisionEntity` annotated class with the `@Entity` annotation and then specify the listener in the `@RevisionEntity` annotation's value attribute.  If you'd rather, you should be able to use `org.hibernate.envers.revision_listener` to specifying the fully qualified class name of the listener class otherwise.
3. Is your `MyService` injectable in any other spring bean?
   Perhaps the issue here is that Spring simply isn't constructing your `MyService` bean in the first place, which would lead to the dependency injection not supplying an implementation during bean injection of the revision listener.

I have created a small demo [here](https://github.com/Naros/hibernate-envers-spring) that you can reference.  I will look into publishing a blog post about this on the Hibernate blog later in the month.

---

**UPDATE**

Just looking at the Spring Framework source briefly, I believe the issue is that you're manually creating a `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`, which when the bean factory gets injected, does not actually create the necessary Hibernate configuration for dependency injection to happen.

What I think you may need to do is manually set this yourself:

```
@Bean
@DependsOn({"dataSource"})
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
   // Create the LocalContainerEntityManagerBean like you were

   // Pass beanFactory here so right configuration gets applied
   em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties(beanFactory));
   return em;
}

private Properties additionalProperties(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
  // add your properties here like you were before
  Properties properties = new Properties();

  // THIS HERE IS THE CRITICAL SETTING
  properties.put(
    "hibernate.resource.beans.container", 
     new SpringBeanContainer(beanFactory));

  return properties
}
```

While the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` is `BeanFactoryAware`, it simply sets an internal property and that's it.  That property does not actually get set as the necessary configuration property for Hibernate to detect it, therefore Hibernate ends up defaulting to CDI injection since you're in a CDI environment.

In the above, as the EntityManagerFactory bean is being constructed, we have the configuration pass in the *BeanFactory* instance.  We pass that factory down into `additionalProperties` where we manually apply it to the right Hibernate configuration and that gets passed to the Hibernate bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks for creating the demo project. I checked your all three points, everything looks fine but it's still not working.. All my "spring" libraries are in 5.1.7.RELEASE versions except spring-data-jpa 1.11.3 and
spring-data-commons 1.13.3. My revision entity has got an annotation @RevisionEntity(ExtendedRevisionListener.class) and the service is injectable in other spring beans, Hibernate libraries from my libs: hibernate-envers-5.3.9.Final, hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final, hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.4.Final, hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-10.2.Final. I have no idea what can be wrong :(

Comment: Spring Data has a `spring-data-envers` library, you aren't using that are you?  Would you be able to put together a simple example like mine where it does not work and share it with me so I can look?

Comment: I don't use the spring-data-envers library. Putting an example could be problematic because it's a bigger project with wicket run on the wildFly 16.

Comment: Do you setup an `EntityManagerFactoryBean` or a `SessionFactoryBean` in your Spring configuration?  I'm curious if this has something to do with JPA vs ORM5 running under WF vs non-WF with how Spring integrates with this `BeanContainer` feature in ORM 5.3.

Comment: So can you enable debug logging for `org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl` and check to see during bootstrap that you see an entry that says `Instantiating session factory with properties` and verify that `hibernate.resource.beans.container` is present and it points to a `SpringBeanContainer`?

Comment: i have extended my question to "answer" your two last comments. I don't see the hibernate.resource.beans.container or the SpringBeanContainer in debug logs.

Comment: If you do not see that, in short the spring bean injection isn't being wired and so that is why the listener isn't being injected.  This most likely is something to do with how the application is configured.  I would suggest you create a small mock project like your main application similar to my demo and open a jira issue and attach the project.  There is clearly something wrong and its either in your configuration or how the spring app gets bootstraped under WildFly.  Can you show how you configure Hibernate on the spring side?

Comment: I have added the hibernate configuration in spring to my original question.

Comment: I don't believe Spring automatically injects the necessary configuration by default when setting up the Spring integration as you have.  I've added some details for you to test with to see if that fixes your issue.  Essentially what I have provided should force Spring to be the dependency injection source rather than CDI.  Be mindful you can't mix Spring and CDI, it must be one or the other from the vantage point of Hibernate's bean registry support.

Comment: After putting your suggested changes "stantiating session factory with properties has got a hibernate.resource.beans.container=org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringBeanContainer@37e53d83," but the injection still not working.

Comment: Then open a jira with a basic webapp that reproduces the issue.  If you can configure the webapp to run with thorntail that would be great and attach it to the jira so I can take a look.

Comment: @Naros just to let you know, I couldn't get the dependency injetion to work without using `@Service` in the RevisionListener implementation. Check this out: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-envers/issues/249

Answer (score 3):

I am using Spring Boot 3.1.1 with Hibernate 6.2 and neither of the answers did work for me. Instead, I could solve it the following way:

**application.yml**

```
spring.jpa.properties:
  hibernate:
    # see https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/6.2/migration-guide.adoc#cdi
    cdi.extensions: false
```

**RevisionListener**

```
public class MyRevisionListener implements RevisionListenere {

    private final MyService myService;

    public MyRevisionListener (@org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy MyService myService) {
        this.myService = myService;
    }

    @Override
    public void newRevision(Object revisionEntity) {
        MyRevisionEntity revinfo = (MyRevisionEntity) revisionEntity;

        // Use myService here to set something on MyRevisionEntity
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be due to a bug where Envers interprets the `cdi.extensions` properly incorrectly: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/jira/software/c/projects/HHH/issues/HHH-16881. (Normally it should be `cdi.extensions: true`)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Spring Boot, it is best to use ApplicationContextAware:

```
public class MyRevisionListener implements RevisionListener, ApplicationContextAware {

    private MyService myService;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.myService = applicationContext.getBean(MyService.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void newRevision(Object revisionEntity) {
        MyRevisionEntity revinfo = (MyRevisionEntity) revisionEntity;

        // Use myService here to set something on MyRevisionEntity
    }

}
```

This was tested using Spring Boot 2.3.9.

Answer (score 2):

Have other way... you can use the static class from spring....

Check....

```
import org.hibernate.envers.RevisionListener;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;


public class EnverRevisionListener implements RevisionListener{

    @Override
    public void newRevision(Object revisionEntity) {
        EnverRevisionEntity revEntity = (EnverRevisionEntity) revisionEntity;
        SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        Authentication auth = context.getAuthentication();
        revEntity.setUserName(auth.getName());
    }

}
```