# Spring Boot JPA interaction from reactive AMQP background thread

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-envers

We have a regular, blocking Spring Boot (2.5.4) application serving a REST interface. We use Hibernate envers for audit logging. This service sends messages on our Service Bus in an asynchronous fashion via the `ServiceBusSenderAsyncClient` from the Azure SDK.
Now this service needs to receive messages from said Service Bus and write updates to the Database - also async. For this we use `ServiceBusReceiverAsyncClient` with a reactive stream. All of this generally works (I wrapped the whole database interaction in one `Transactional` function) but I'm encountering issues with envers via the `beforeTransactionCompletion callback` being `null` (when I deactivate envers, it works). This issues is Service Bus independent from my understanding and really rotates around accessing the JPA repo from a background thread. Following the schematic implementation:

**ServiceBusReceiveController**

```
@Component
public class SubscriptionReceiveController {
  @Autowired
  private MyService myService;

  @Autowired
  private ServiceBusReceiverAsyncClient receiver;

  @Autowired
  private ObjectMapper mapper;

  @PostConstruct
  public void run() {
    // continuously receive messages in the background
    receiver.receiveMessages().flatMap(message -> {
      MyObject object;
      try {
        object = mapper.readValue(message.getBody().toString(), MyClass.class);
      } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        throw new JsonProcessingRuntimeException("Failed to convert message to object", e);
      }

      // wrap the blocking JPA interaction
      Mono<MyObject> blockingWrapper = Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
        return myService.updateMyObject(object.getId());
      });

      // When the service returns, this is where it crashes
      return blockingWrapper.subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
    }).flatMap(response -> {
      // More processing steps
    }).subscribe();
  }
}
```

**MyService**

```
@Service
public class MyService {

  @Autowired
  private MyRepository myRepository;

  @Transactional
  public MyObject updateMyObject(UUID objectId) {
    var object = myRepository.getById(objectId);
    object.setSomeProperty("myPropertyValue");

    return myRepository.save(object);
  }
}
```

Causing following **error message**:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Unable to perform beforeTransactionCompletion callback: null; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to perform beforeTransactionCompletion callback: null
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to perform beforeTransactionCompletion callback: null
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue$BeforeTransactionCompletionProcessQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:960) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:525) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2381) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:448) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:562) ~[spring-orm-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        ... 20 common frames omitted

...

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at com.my.package.revision.AuditRevisionListener.newRevision(AuditRevisionListener.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.hibernate.envers.internal.revisioninfo.DefaultRevisionInfoGenerator.generate(DefaultRevisionInfoGenerator.java:88) ~[hibernate-envers-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
        at org.hibernate.envers.internal.synchronization.AuditProcess.getCurrentRevisionData(AuditProcess.java:133) ~[hibernate-envers-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
        at org.hibernate.envers.internal.synchronization.AuditProcess.executeInSession(AuditProcess.java:115) ~[hibernate-envers-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
        at org.hibernate.envers.internal.synchronization.AuditProcess.doBeforeTransactionCompletion(AuditProcess.java:174) ~[hibernate-envers-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
        at org.hibernate.envers.internal.synchronization.AuditProcessManager$1.doBeforeTransactionCompletion(AuditProcessManager.java:47) ~[hibernate-envers-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue$BeforeTransactionCompletionProcessQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:954) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
        ... 28 common frames omitted
```

What am I missing here, why is the transaction not fully finished within the Service implementation? Is there a better way/pattern for a background thread to write to a database via JPA?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

null pointer exception is here:
`com.my.package.revision.AuditRevisionListener.newRevision(AuditRevisionListener.java:10)`
nothing to do with transactions?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem with RevisionListener. It seems that there is a lack of communication between Spring Framework and Hibernate Envers as described in this issue:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-envers/issues/249.

Even after annotating my CustomRevisionListener with `@Service`, spring cannot find this bean and create an instance of it.

I've tried all the solutions listed here:
[How to inject spring beans into the hibernate envers RevisionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57902388/)

But only the solution using the `SecurityContextHolder` (Solution 3) worked for me. I just needed to check if my entity that represents the logged user had an Id property and fill it with the user id that was retrieved from the database.

Here is my code:

```
public class MyRevisionListener implements RevisionListener {

   @Override
   public void newRevision(Object entity) {
      MyRevisionEntity revisionEntity = (MyRevisionEntity) entity;

      Long loggedUserId = Optional.ofNullable(SecurityContextHolder.getContext())
            .map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication)
            .filter(Authentication::isAuthenticated)
            .map(Authentication::getPrincipal)
            .map(JwtUser.class::cast)
            .map(JwtUser::getId)
            .orElse(null);

      revisionEntity.setUserId(loggedUserId);
      revisionEntity.setDate(new Date());    
   }
}
```